# PHP Registry has a deprecated constructor Error

Tags: php, class, constructor

I am having `Registry has a deprecated constructor`Error while running a php script.it shows the error on line 261. Going to that line I am having below codes.How to avoid this error.

```
class Registry {

function Registry() {

    define("CWD", ($getcwd = getcwd() ? $getcwd : "."));
    $config = array();
    include INCLUDES . "config.php";

    if (sizeof($config) == 0) {
        if (file_exists(INCLUDES . "config.php")) {
            exit( "<div style=\"border: 1px dashed #cc0000;font-family:Tahoma;background-color:#FBEEEB;width:100%;padding:10px;color:#cc0000;\"><strong>Welcome to EvolutionScript 5.1 FULL</strong><a></a><br>Before you can begin using EvolutionScript you need to perform the installation procedure. <a href=\"" . (file_exists( "install/install.php" ) ? "" : "../") . "install/install.php\" style=\"color:#000;\">Click here to begin ...</a><br></div>" );
        }
        else {
            exit("<br /><br /><strong>Configuration</strong>: includes/config.php does not exist. Please fill out the data in config.php.new and rename it to config.php");
        }
    }

    $this->config = $config;

    define("TABLE_PREFIX", trim($this->config['Database']['tableprefix']));
    define("COOKIE_PREFIX", (empty($this->config['Misc']['cookieprefix']) ? "ptc" : $this->config['Misc']['cookieprefix']) . "_");
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `__construct()` instead of `Registry()`

Comment: I think you should use `function __construct() {}` instead `function Registry() {}`

Comment: class Registry {

Comment: The answer is in the top:  [Deprecated features in PHP 7.0.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php)

Comment: while using function __construct() page not working

Comment: "It's not working." sigh... Anything more?

Answer (score 0):

Constructors named the same as class name are considered PHP4 style and got deprecated since PHP 7. I know it's common to use such convention in other OOP languages but PHP promotes magic method named `__construct()` instead. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php